# Amazon's aws cli times out on macOS 10.12.5

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I just installed the [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (via `pip install awscli` per Amazon's [installation instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html)) on macOS 10.12.5. The installation completed without issue. But when I run the app (e.g. $ `aws help`) it just hangs for about a minute and finally fails with:

```
$ aws help
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

I've tried running it from both Python 3.6.1 and 2.7.13 environments. The macOS firewall is disabled so I'm not blocking any outbound requests.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very strange behaviour. The AWS CLI does not activate `ssh`.

I would suggest that you have another script called `aws` somewhere in your PATH that you previously used to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance, and that script is running rather than the AWS CLI.

Run this command to discover which one it is running:

```
$ which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

In this case, mine is in `$ /usr/local/bin/aws help`, but yours is likely to be elsewhere.

To run the correct one, use:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/aws help
```